# How to iterate through retrieved object using Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m using Core Data and trying to iterate through objects I’m retrieving. I’m getting an error in Xcode.

```
// Fetching Records and saving it in "fetchedRecordsArray" object
self.fetchedRecordsArray = [appDelegate getAllPhoneBookRecords];

//print array
NSLog(@"Count: %lu", (unsigned long)self.fetchedRecordsArray.count);

for (id object in self.fetchedRecordsArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", object.city);
}
```

Count returns 6 so I know there are objects in there. I also know ‘city’ is an attribute in my entity. The error I get is:

```
Property ‘city’ not found on object of type ‘const _strong id’
```

Any advice on how to fix this and log what’s being returned properly?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I have to say it - calling down to you app delegate to retrieve model objects is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this

```
            for (id object in self.fetchedRecordsArray) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.city);
            }

            to 

            for (objectClassName *object in self.fetchedRecordsArray) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.city);
            }
```

NOTE: *object not object - in for loop

Answer (score 4):

instead of iterating on objects why not iterate on your entity.

```
for(<your entity class> obj in self.fetchedRecordsArray){
   //do stuff
}
```

or if the fetched records contain multiple types of entities.

```
for(id obj in self.fetchedRecordsArray){
    if([obj isKindOfClass:<you entity class>.class]){
    //do stuff
    }
    else if([obj isKindOfClass:<you other entity class>.class]){
     //do other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for iterating through objects, you can also check for entity of object , where Objects is array of objects

```
for (NSManagedObject *obj in Objects)
{

        if ([[obj entity].name isEqualToString:@"EntityName1"])
        {
           do stuff...
        }

        else if ([[obj entity].name isEqualToString:@"EntityName2"])
        {
           do stuff...
        }
}
```

Hope this helps